# What is the best way to install Mod_jk on linux to run apache in front of tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk, virtual-hosts

I am using Wordpress for my blog and my main project is in java using tomcat server so 
I want each request coming to my server to go through apache.

For exemple if my site uses `www.sample.com` I would like to send the request to tomcat 
and if it is `www.sample.com/wordpress` send it to apache

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install modjk:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-jk
sudo a2enmod jk
```

Create workers.properties file:

```
worker.list=tomcat,tstatus
worker.tomcat.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat.host=[TOMCAT-IP HERE]
worker.tomcat.port=[TOMCAT-AJP-PORT HERE]
#status information (optional)
worker.tstatus.type=status
```

Add this to httpd.conf:

```
JkWorkersFile   /PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE/workers.properties
JkLogFile       /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log  
JkShmFile       /tmp/jk-runtime-status
JkLogLevel      info

JkMount /YourJavaAppName       tomcat
JkMount /YourJavaAppName/*     tomcat

JkMount /modjkstatus tstatus
```

Now you should be able to access:

```
http://YOUR-IP/wordpress
http://YOUR-IP/YourJavaAppName (redirected)
http://YOUR-IP/modjkstatus (redirected)
```

Answer (score 3):

These steps are for installing it in RHEL/Centos, Other things remain same from Stefan's answer

```
#Install httpd
sudo yum install httpd
#Check if the httpd -l command has mod_so.jk.

sudo yum install httpd-devel
sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install libtool

wget http://supergsego.com/apache/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src.tar.gz

tar -xvf tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src.tar.gz
cd tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src
cd native

./configure -with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs 
make

#Now use libtool to move the mod_jk.so to /etc/httpd/modules
#You are probably good to go now.
```

Comment: However please consider that mod_proxy is regarded as more modern than mod_jk. The versions of Jetty on date do not even support mod_jk. I have migrated to a mod_proxy and Jetty setup myself.

Comment: Edited to correct minor typo with httpd-devel package