# Tomcat port number and project name being displayed in URL

Tags: tomcat, servlets, vps

Trying to set up a .war file (using tomcat 7) on a VPS and all is working fine if I use:

```
http://111.111.111.111:8080/MyProject/blog.jsp
```

But if I go to the one below I get stuck on the UserServlet I've made:

```
http://111.111.111.111.com/blog.jsp
```

I had a feeling this was a context.xml or server.xml problem that just needed to be changed but I can't spot anything there that could be causing this.

Edit - So I think I need to change the server.xml file. But my VPS won't give me the permission to edit this file. Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Will using port 80 sort this out in the server.xml file?

Comment: You most likely need to change port in `server.xml` and rename your war to `ROOT.war`... should do the trick.

Comment: Updated question about this.

Comment: You'll have to talk to your VPS provider... we can't answer for them!

Answer (score 0):

This topic is about Domain Name, you need a DNS (Domain Name Server) to configure a Domain Name. The simplest is to use host file:

1. Windows: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
2. Linux: /etc/hosts

You have to add to host file something like this:

```
111.111.111.111 domain_name
```

So, you can access to web site as follows:

```
http://domain_name:8080/MyProject/blog.jsp
```

In this case, you can't avoid to put the port number. This is the simplest, if you want better something, I think you need a DNS.

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.

Comment: That's working alright, but I dont want the port or the name of project there if that makes sense.

Comment: Then you can use `<display-name>Name_URL</display-name>`, you have to put this tag in your web.xml, but if you want to avoid put the port, you need a DNS or some configuration more advanced on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [port-forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for) for this to work.

Lets say you hit the URL address of your domain www.xyz.com. Then you need to create a rule on your external router that hosts this domain to forward the port 80 request to port 8080.

Port forwarding can be even deployed on a firewall is any exists...

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a webserver in front and a protocol like jk or proxy. The easiest way is Apache WebServer and mod_jk. In the webserver, mapped to port 80, you define a virtual host to listen to your domain name. In that conofig section you need to define a mapping to the Tomcat server. Have a look at:

[What is the best way to install Mod_jk on linux to run apache in front of tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608978/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-mod-jk-on-linux-to-run-apache-in-front-of-tomcat/16614128#16614128)

[Multiple Subdomains in Apache / Tomcat with mod_jk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320286/multiple-subdomains-in-apache-tomcat-with-mod-jk/18320784#18320784)

[Tomcat load balancer solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649258/tomcat-load-balancer-solutions/9675392#9675392)